# Trouble when returning non pointer object in a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, core-location, nsvaluetransformer, github-mantle

I'm using Mantle to help me transform model objects to JSON. One of my objects contains a `centroid` property defined as follows:

`@property (assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D centroid;`

When I deal with the server I receive the property in this format:

```
centroid: {
      lat: "38.416600086777166",
      lon: "-88.29868011101323"
    }
```

So I decided to implement a custom JSON transformer that's available in the `MTLJSONSerializing` protocol, defined as follows:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer*)centroidJSONTransformer {
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^CLLocationCoordinate2D(NSDictionary *dict) {
        NSNumber *latitude = dict[@"lat"];
        NSNumber *longitude = dict[@"lon"];

        return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([latitude doubleValue], [longitude doubleValue]);
    }];
}
```

The trouble that I run into is that the `+ (instancetype)transformerWithBlock:(MTLValueTransformerBlock)transformationBlock` method inside of `MTLValueTransformer` takes in a block of type `typedef id (^MTLValueTransformerBlock)(id);`, which returns a value of type `id` or any objective-c pointer object.

However what I would like to do instead is return the CLLocationCoordinate2D type, which is a scalar, non-`id` type. Short of defining my own custome implementation of `transformerWithBlock:` is there a clean way I can make this happen?

Comment: try wrap it with `NSValue`

Comment: Which API? The only generic API of `NSValue` is `+ valueWithNonretainedObject:` which takes in id-type objects as opposed to scalars.

Comment: @AndrewLauerBarinov, see my answer, but that's not true. NSValue has several methods for wrapping various kinds of values including arbitrary scalar values, pointers, and NSRanges. The `+valueWithNonretainedObject:` is probably the least used of the NSValue convenience functions.

Comment: Yup @AndrewMadsen I'm noticing it now. I was just looking at the available APIs from autocomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap primitive/scalar values in NSValue to pass them to/from methods, functions, or blocks expecting an `id`:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&coordinate objCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];
```

Then, to get the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` back out:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
[value getValue:&coordinate];
```

As of iOS 6 (and presumably OS X 10.8, though I haven't checked), there's the [NSValue MapKit Additions category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/NSValue_MapKit_additions/Reference/Reference.html) which adds methods to NSValue to wrap and unwrap `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:coordinate];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [value MKCoordinateValue];
```